# Angular UI-Bootstrap Multiple Checkboxes Filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I want to filter my data with multiple checkboxes. One variable can have multiple filters.

[Here is the link](http://plnkr.co/edit/7sutGrnZ8GOrV2tcnNRS?p=preview)

So for example when 4 and 5 are checked, all 4s and 5s are shwon.

html:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <pre>{{checkboxes}}</pre>
    <companies ng-repeat="check in checkboxes">
      <button type="button" class="btn"  ng-model="check.truth" 
      btn-checkbox-true="check.value" btn-checkbox>{{check.value}}</button>
    </companies>
</div>
```

and js:

```
$scope.checkboxes = [{"value":"1","truth":false},{"value":"2","truth":false}, {"value":"3","truth":false},{"value":"4","truth":false}];


$scope.data = [{"name":"Some Name","value":"1"},{"name":"Another Name","value":"2"},{"name":"Cool Name","value":"3"},{"name":"Funky Name","value":"4"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom filter

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in data | myfilter:checkboxes">

app.filter('myfilter', function () {
    return function (data, values) {
        var vs = [];
        angular.forEach(values, function (item) {
            if ( !! item.truth) {
                vs.push(item.value);
            }
        });

        if (vs.length === 0) return data;

        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(data, function (item) {
            if (vs.indexOf(item.value) >= 0) {
                result.push(item);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lQkgcbe0APt5rsx83iKD?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: How would that work for strings (eg. the names column)? Why doesnt `if(vs == item.value){result.push(item);` work?

Comment: @scr- `vs` is an array, `vs.indexOf(item.value) >= 0` checks whether the array contains the string.

Comment: Cant get it to work for the names column: http://plnkr.co/edit/TBXyBiYta84fyqNu4wJW?p=preview